# I cannot change python 2.6.1 to 3.4.2

Tags: python

I am totally stumped, when I type in Python it comes up with 2.6.1. I have typed in

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3:${PATH}" 
export PATH
```

nothing happens when I type in Python it comes up with the same 2.6.1

Any Help reuired and appreciated

Comment: The thing in that `bin` folder is called `python3` not `python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a file path, not a dir path here:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3:${PATH}"
```

It should be:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/:${PATH}"
```

Also, you when you type `python`, `python3` executable will not be launched, because it will look for `python` file.

You can create a symlink `python` which points to `.../3.4/bin/python3`

Comment: excuse my idiocy but how do you make it a dir path so version 3.4 is the one I am using

Comment: In the current configuration you can't, because there is no file called `python` in directory `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin` which you are adding to `PATH`. You should use `python3` or make a symlink. See my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `python` refers to `python2`. If you want `python3`, you'll have to explicitly tell so.

If it can be changed on Mac (you are on Mac, aren't you?) is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both.

If you want to use python3, type `python3`