# Can't change 2.6.1 to 3.4.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I asked this question earlier and thought I had it sussed but no I'm stuck again

My default python is set to 2.6.1. I have Python 3.4.1 installed and can run it by typing Python3.

however when I type in `python manage.py runserver` I get

```
 TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings
```

I am sure my version of Django does not support 2.6.1.

I am trying to change it to 3.4.1. I managed to get it by using virtualenv earlier but I am now completely stuck.

when I try python3 manage.py runsserver

I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Then when I open up python3 and "import django" the response is

```
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583277/i-cannot-change-python-2-6-1-to-3-4-2 ?

Comment: Because I am stuck and don't how to fix it. Sorry if I am looking for help.

Comment: well that's pretty obvious you haven't installed `django` under your virtualenv, so you get the `ImportError`

Comment: can you please explain how to install django under virtualenv please Anzel

Comment: well that's how you install without virtualenv in the first place? just `pip install django`.
Also, to use **python3** as default **python**, depending if you're using **bash**, just add alias to your `.basrc`, `alias python=python3`

Comment: Thankyou Anzel, your a kind individual. SORTED :))))

Comment: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/